# Some xml files in layout folder are small, some are normal

Tags: android, screen

I created xml files for different screen sizes. 
I have layout, layout-large, layout-normal and layout-xlarge folders. 
In layout folder some of the xml files are shown as small screen on visual editor. 
here is my manifest codes

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- large screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <!-- xlarge screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

why some xml files are shown as small screens? 
One of xml files is appears narrow and long screen.
Is there a way to define dimensions of xml file?
Thanks